# A problem occurred with this webpage so it was reloaded

Tags: ipad

I believe I am getting this problem  'A problem occurred with this webpage so it was reloaded' because iPad is running out of memory.  As you know Apple had to pay a fine in the USA for obsoleting people's devices with their OS upgrade.

I have wiped my iPad 6th generation and reset it to factory mode and installed no applications except Firefox.  Then Safari and Forefox both crash on every web page.

OS Version 13.3.1.

So it there a way to turn off some features since iOS obviously has consumed my device to the extent that it keeps crashing.

Answer (score -1):

iOS 13.4.1 fixed it.  Apple must have known it was a bug.